# Openslide won't show the mmpx property for level_count-1

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, openslide

The property "openslide.mmp-x" shows the property containing the number of microns per pixel in the X dimension of level 0. As I am showing the level_count-1 I don't want the property for level 0 but for level_count-1. How do I get that property of that level?

```
slide = openslide.OpenSlide(SVSFileName)

# get width, height of image at low-res reading magnification
lrHeight = slide.level_dimensions[slide.level_count - 1][1]
lrWidth = slide.level_dimensions[slide.level_count - 1][0]

mmx = slide.properties['openslide.mpp-x']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
slide.level_downsamples

-> (1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0)
```

gives you how the levels do the downsampling, and I think we may calculate the mpp-x/mpp-y by the downsample rates for each level.

Another option is using lib called [large-image](https://digitalslidearchive.github.io/HistomicsTK/examples/wsi-io-using-large-image.html#getMagnificationForLevel()):

it's getNativeMagnification method will give you mpp_x for each level.